# Fetch API: how to wait until the whole response is downloaded without consuming it?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a utility method in my React app for making HTTP requests.
The method implements [fetch timeout using AbortController](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/951).
What I'd like to get as a return value is a **fully resolved Response**. Here's *my* definition:
calling any method on this resolved response object should *not* result in network packets being sent or received. Plus, the body of this response should not be consumed.

Here's what I'm doing right now (not sure about this):

```
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 5000);
  const response = await fetch(url, { signal: controller.signal })
  const clone = response.clone();

  // a call to initiate body transfer via network
  const text = await clone.text();

  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  return response;
```

When I call `response.json()` afterward, what exactly will happen? Will there be any network communication?

Comment: this is very confusing to me, when you call any method on the resolved response why should it result in further requests/responses? What do you want to achieve? What is you current and your expected result? Why do you want a timeout when your question titles "wait until response.."

Comment: @johnSmith well, I assume that since response.text() is a promise and can be called just once it has something to do with the network.

Comment: [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) reads the body "to completion". So `response` is not a "fully resolved Response" according to your definition. You would have to call the `Blob`-derived method to get the data first. Note, however, that using [`clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) cloning the response does not clone the data retrieved from the body, so the code shown, calling `clone.text()`, would have no affect on `response`. The point of `clone()` is to be able to consume the Body multiple times.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if I remove clone & await clone.text(), my method will exit as soon as the response headers are read. This means that reading the body of the response outside of my util method may still take forever (and go over my configured timeout) or not succeed at all. So, I'm trying to download the response body inside my util method and wait until it completes (within the timeout), so the outer code does not have to wait for it. 

I understand that cloning & consuming the body of a clone may not do what I want, but then how to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think you can. The Fetch API is not able to provide the infrastructure needed to accomplish what you want to do. You could look at using XMLHttpRequest, which has a different mechanism for timeouts and aborting than fetch.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you! And if I don't want to go down to XMLHttpRequest, I guess my options are: 1) abandon the utility method and always call response.json()/text()/blob() before clearTimeout; 2) switch to Axios?

Comment: Axios uses `fetch` AFAIK... Maybe it switches to XHR for some features? You could look at their code if it does what you want.